# Yii2 page reloads automatically

Tags: jquery, yii2

In yii2, I have created two tables sales and sales_items. Sales has only customer id, primary key and defaults. Sales_items has items and details for every sales id. I created a form with CRUD contains

1. customer_id
2. product_id
3. quantity
4. unit_price

In the list product_id, quantity, unit_price are from sales_item models and customer_id is from sales model.

I placed sales_item model inside a div and clone them with a add item button,Issue is when I clone them for the first time it creates a copy perfectly, but when I click it on the second time the whole page reloads, I have no idea whats going on, need help

my sales.js

```
$("#add-item").on('click', function(){
    clone_count = clone_count+1;
    var clone = $(".items:first").clone();//.items is the enclosing div
    clone.insertAfter(".items:first");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used button tag without type attribute, it worked as submit in my browser(mozilla). The solution is to give type attribute as button to my button tag or use input tag with type button. Anyway an another learning. Got the answer from [Yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69899-yii2-page-reloads-automatically/page__gopid__296748#entry296748).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what's happening it's hard to tell what may be wrong. It sounds possible that the button you click is replaced, which causes it to lose the event handler. If that is the issue, you can attach the event handler on an element that remains on the page, e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', "#add-item", function(){ ... });
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I tried your options as well. But it seems like it is affected by some internal js from Yii2